# How to properly receive hex data from serial communication in linux

Tags: c, linux, hex

I have been searching for this similar issue on internet but haven't found any good solution. I am in ubuntu and I am receiving serial hex data on serial port. I have connected my system using null modem cable to windows system and windows system is running docklight software which is sending hex data like below:

```
2E FF AA 4F CC 0D
```

Now by saving the data, I do not mean that I want to print data on terminal. I just want to save this data as it is in a buffer so that I an later process it.

To read the data I am doing

```
res = read (fd, buf, sizeof buf)
//where buf is 
unsigned char buf[255];
```

At this point after reading, buf contains some random chars. From some links on internet, I got a way to convert it into hex:

```
unsinged char hexData[255];
for (int i = 0; i < res; i++)
{
    sprintf((char*)hexData+i*2, "%02X", buf[i]);
}
```

Now this hexData contains `2EFFAA4FCC0D`, which is ok for my purpose. (I do not know if it is the right way of doing it or not). Now lets say I want to convert `E` from the hexData into decimal. But at this point, `E` will be considered as character not a hex so may be I'll get 69 instead of 14.

How can I save hex data in a variable. Should I save it as array of chars or int. Thanks.

Comment: It is not clear what you are receiving or what you want from it.  It seems that the peer is sending ASCII hex data, but it's not clear whether there are spaces or not in the char stream - '2E FF AA 4F CC 0D' suggests ASCII hex bytes separated by a white space, whereas 'hexData+i*2' suggests that there are no spaces.  'How can I save hex data in a variable. Should I save it as array of chars or int' is meaningless since you could either, or neither, or something else, with what is just serial bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have data in binary form in `buf`

But if you still need to convert hex to decimal, you can use `sscanf`

```
sscanf(&hexBuf[i],"%02X",&intVar);// intVar is integer variable
```

It wll convert hex byte formed by `hexBuf[i]` and `hexBuf[i+1]` to binary in `intVar`, When you printf `intVar` with `%d` you will get to see the decimal value

You can store `intVar` as element of `unsigned character` array

Answer (score 1):

You may want to think about what you're trying to achieve.

Hexadecimal is just a representation. The byte you are receiving could be shown as hexadecimal pairs, as binary octet or as a series of (more or less) printable characters (what you see if you print your `unsigned char` array).

If what you need is storing only the hexadecimal representation of those bytes, convert them to hexadecimal as you are doing, but remember you'll need an array twice as big as your buffer (since a single byte will be represented by two hexadecimal characters once you convert it).

Usually, the best thing to do is to keep them as an array of bytes (`char`s), that is, your `buf` array, and only convert them when you need to show the hexadecimal representation.